# Jquery .append array: reference an array by value contained within

Tags: jquery, arrays, append

I am currently using .append to join two or more arrays together to form a phrase as you can see in this jsfiddle: [jsfiddle append array](http://jsfiddle.net/Ntdsm/).

```
function P1(phrase) {
    var sen = ('<a class="senword">' + phrase[0] + '<br/>' + phrase[1] + ' </a>');
       return sen;
}

var words = [
['one', '一'],    
['eight','八'],
['hundred','百'],
];

$("#onehundred").append(P1(words[0])).append(P1(words[2]));
$("#eighthundred").append(P1(words[1])).append(P1(words[2]));
```

However I need a way to append arrays by using an array value, e.g. 'hundred' instead of the index number e.g. [2].  This is because each time I add new vocabulary to the 'words' array, the index number is obviously changing, which means I would need to manually change all the index numbers for the phrases.

So is there a way to join arrays by using a value instead of an index number, as this value wouldn't change no matter how many new words I added?

For example instead of:

```
$("#onehundred").append(P1(words[0])).append(P1(words[2]));
```

Have something like this (but obviously this is not correct):

```
$("#onehundred").append(P1(words['one'])).append(P1(words['hundred']));
```

PS
I don't mind changing to a literal array if it helps, e.g.:

```
var words = [
{'english':'hundred', 'chinese':'百'},
];
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Change `words` to a json format string and convert it to an object with `parseJSON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your data structure to an object:

```
var words = {
    'one': '一',    
    'eight': '八',
    'hundred': '百'
};
```

Then change your `P1` function to accept the property name, and have it do the look-up...

```
function P1(key) {
    var sen = ('<a class="senword">' + words[key] + '<br/>' + key + ' </a>');
       return sen;
}
```

And then just pass the property name...

```
$("#onehundred").append(P1('one')).append(P1('hundred'));
$("#eighthundred").append(P1('eight')).append(P1('hundred'));
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/DgAzz/

---

If you can't change the initial structure, then create the object from it...

```
var words_map = {};

$.each(words, function(i, val) {
    words_map[val[0]] = val[1];
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/DgAzz/1/

Comment: This looks great, but for ease of explanation I simplified my arrays, each word actually has more than two values, e.g. `['hundred','bǎi','百'],`  which is why I used multiple arrays rather than one object - would your suggestion still be possible?

Comment: @user1218478: So when `'hundred'` is requested, the all of its related values will be concatenated into the string? It shouldn't be any different. Just have the value of each property be an array of strings, like `'hundered': ['bǎi','百']`.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise you could do that! So the last piece of the puzzle would be how to reference each array element in `var sen = ('<a class="senword">' + words[key] + '<br/>' + key + ' </a>');` ?

Comment: @user1218478: Since `words[key]` is referencing an Array, you'd get them by numeric index... `words[key][0]`, `words[key][1]`, etc... Or if there may be different quantities, and they're to be joined by a consistent string like a `<br>`, you could use `words[key].join('<br>')`. **DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DgAzz/2/

Comment: I think that's solved it! I've been researching for days and you answered it all in 23 minutes!  Thank you so much and I've learnt a great deal!